# How to organise complex styling rules in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, vector-layer

For example, my "roads" vector layer has the following attributes:

- road type: primary, secondary, local, track, or path
- surface: sealed, or unsealed
- segment type: road, bridge, tunnel, floodway, culvert, and few more types
- relevancy: 1..9 (related to scale / zoom level)

Which yields almost 1000 unique styles but only 10% is present in data (for example, there are no unsealed primary roads)

In general styling rules are simple:

- any path should be dashed black line (0.25mm pen width)
- any unsealed road should be dashed
- primary and secondary roads should be red (0.6mm pen width)
- local roads and tracks should be orange (0.4mm pen width)
- tracks should be dashed
- each segment type has specific rendering:

  - road: no change
  - tunnel: keep colour and pen width but change line to dotted and draw portals
  - and so on ..

So far, I've tried to use "Single Symbol" based on segment type and then use "Expression" for colour, pen width & style. I couldn't figure out how deal with relevancy so I switched to "Rule-based".

"Rule-based" can deal with relevancy, but number of rules is high. I can't figure out how use "Refine selected rule" > "Add categories to rule" to change pen style only and keep the colour.

In both cases I have to copy attribute expressions across the rules (not sure if there is a concept of "global" expression) and it's tedious to keep then in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by defining some basic rules using Filtering. For instance:

```
"road"='Primary' or "road"='Secondary'
```

Then try working with "Refine Selected Rule" > "Add categories to Rule" and in Column use an expression to concatenate two of your next attributes, like:

```
concat("surface",' ',"segment_type")
```

and classify the expressions and adjust the symbols accordingly.

Comment: I do not like the "filtering" bit because then I have to add "roads" layer multiple times.

Comment: @mys The rule based renderer works on a single layer.

Answer (score 4):

The following approach is simple to use and avoids duplication of styling rules:

QGIS allows to define custom fields: "Layer Properties" -> "Fields". The best result is achieved by defining a new field for each style using expression. For example `style_colour` is defined as

```
case
  when  "roadtype" = "path" then 'black'
  when "surface" in (0,1) then 'red'
  else '#FF7518'
end
```

Expression should produce a valid value for given style.

(Tip: previously defined fields can be used in expressions)

Then use rule based filtering using (segment `segment_type` in my case) to define individual symbols (road on bridge, in tunnel, floodway, ...).

Then set "Color" to "Attribute Field" (using drop down next to colour picker") and assign `style_colour` field. Repeat this for the remaining styles.